# database query not working well with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Good evening everyone, while studying i came across PHP if, else and elseif statements. I am trying to put if and else to use but the IF statement is really not working. Maybe I'm missing a tiny detail. The code is suposed to check if the username is already in the table and then skip. Any help will be greatly appreciated. If this question has been answered here, kindly point me to teh URL

```
<?php
include 'inc.dbcon.php';
// Report all errors
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username'][0]);
$school = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['school'][0]);
$candname = $_POST['candname'];

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM parlia_votes WHERE username='".$username."'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
?>
<script>
    alert('Vote has already been cast.');
    window.location = 'logout.php'; 
</script>
<?php
}
else
    foreach ($_POST['candname'] as $candname) {
        $query = sprintf("INSERT INTO parlia_votes (username, school, candname) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')", $username, $school, $candname);
        ?>
        <script>alert('Thank you for casting your votes.');</script>
        <script>window.location = 'logout.php'; </script>
        <?php
        $con->query($query);
    }
?>
```

PS: I'm using a foreach loop to post to database. thanks

Comment: What, specifically, is not working?

Comment: The else is missing the opening curly bracket

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation, concatenation or `sprintf` to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Accidentally unescaped data is a serious risk. Using bound parameters is less verbose and easier to review to check you’re doing it properly.

Comment: @LordNeo else does not use brackets at all here, foreach has both { and }

Comment: ok... let me give it a try

Comment: One advantage to prepared statements with placeholder values is you can prepare once, then execute the query multiple times with different data. That will really simplify your `for` loop here.

Comment: `$_POST['X'][0]` implies a wider array (than a single) and your statement of: *"The code is suposed to check if the username is already in the table"* - seems to contradict this. You may need to update your question to contain the HTML/form for this.

Comment: @IlyaBursov yup, you're right, the user needs to specify what's not working or what error is getting.

Comment: @LordNeo the curly brackets worked

Comment: Well that's just confusing, else without curly brackets is perfectly valid in this instance.

Comment: @llyaBursov i wasn't getting any error, pop mesaage shows that the data already exist but it goes on to add the record to the table

Comment: Tell me, what shows up when you use error reporting? http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php a parse error perhaps?

Comment: thanks everyone, i'll work on the areas that you have all pointed out and come up with a better version of my code

Comment: @FelicityOkache [This was a question...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45289350/database-query-not-working-well-with-php#comment77541505_45289350); can I too get an answer from this?